# Как в python с помощью условного оператора сделать программу, которая понимала бы русский и английский вариант

Tags: python, python-3.x

В программе определена функция, рисующая пирамиду, принимающая на вход три параметра - цвета каждой из ступеней фигуры. Как сделать так, чтобы программа понимала русский и английский вариант следующих цветов: красный (red), синий (blue), зеленый (green), желтый (yellow) с помощью логического оператора or?

когда пользователь вводит к примеру "red" - программа работает как нужно. Но как мне сделать так, чтобы слово "красный" так же как и "red" передавалось в функцию,

```
from turtle import*

a = input("Цвет первой полосы")
b = input("Цвет второй полосы")
c = input("Цвет третьей полосы")

def pyramid(c1, c2, c3):
    color(c1)
    width(50)
    penup()
    goto(-100, -100)
    pendown()
    forward(200)
    penup()
    goto(60, -50)
    pendown()
    left(180)
    color(c2)
    forward(120)
    color(c3)
    penup()
    goto(-30, 0)
    pendown()
    left(180)
    forward(60)

pyramid(a,b,c)
exitonclick()
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? В любом учебнике полно примеров, как пользоватьcя условным оператором и or. Несложно адаптировать под red и "красный".

Comment: Трудность в том, что не могу понять как полученный цвет от пользователя передать в функцию

Comment: тогда задавайте конкретный вопрос по вашей проблеме с примером кода.

Comment: когда пользователь вводит к примеру "red" - программа работает как нужно. Но как мне сделать так, чтобы слово "красный" так же как и "red" передавалось в функцию, используя условный оператор if

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно писать один и тот же код три раза. Для этого есть функции. Функцию пишешь один раз и используешь столько раз, сколько нужно.

```
from turtle import *

def define_color(): # создаем функцию
    # теперь создаем словарь, в котором хранятся цвета
    # все хранится в одно месте, изменять и дополнять придется только один раз
    colors = {"red": ["red", "красный", "rouge"], # при вводе любого из трех значений цвет будет red
              "green": ["green", "зеленый", "vert"], 
              "blue": ["blue", "синий", "bleu"]}

    # запрашиваем цвет у пользователя
    # lower() приводит к нижнему регистру на случай если введено "Красный"
    user_input = input("Введи название цвета: ").lower() 

    # ищем среди разных значений к какому цвету относится ввод пользователя
    for color in colors:
        if user_input in colors[color]:
            return color

# а теперь вызываем функцию три раза и получаем три цвета
a = define_color()
b = define_color()
c = define_color()
```

Код не идеален и не защищает от ошибок типа ввода несуществующего цвета или ввода с ошибкой. В таком случае результат будет None и пирамидка не нарисуется. Можно добавить в конце `return "black"`, чтобы по умолчанию был черный цвет.

```
for color in colors:
        if user_input in colors[color]:
            return color

return "black"
```

Comment: а мой почти такой же ответ заминусовали :)

Comment: Спасибо! Я как вы пока что не умею(

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за помощь! Решил своими же усилиями. Не ругайтесь за длинный код

```
from turtle import*
a = input("Цвет первой полосы")
if a == "red" or a == "красный":
    a = "red"
elif a == "blue" or a == "синий":
    a = "blue"
elif a == "green" or a == "зеленый":
    a = "green"
else:
    if a == "yellow" or a == "желтый":
        a = "yellow"
b = input("Цвет второй полосы")
if b == "red" or b == "красный":
    b = "red"
elif b == "blue" or b == "синий":
    b = "blue"
elif b == "green" or b == "зеленый":
    b = "green"
else:
    if b == "yellow" or b == "желтый":
        b = "yellow"
c = input("Цвет третьей полосы")
if c == "red" or c == "красный":
    c = "red"
elif c == "blue" or c == "синий":
    c = "blue"
elif c == "green" or c == "зеленый":
    c = "green"
else:
    if c == "yellow" or c == "желтый":
        c = "yellow"
def pyramid1(c1):
    color(c1)
    width(50)
    penup()
    goto(-100, -100)
    pendown()
    forward(200)
    penup()
    goto(60, -50)
    pendown()
    left(180)
def pyramid2(c2):
    color(c2)
    forward(120)
def pyramid(c3):
    color(c3)
    penup()
    goto(-30, 0)
    pendown()
    left(180)
    forward(60)
pyramid1(a)
pyramid2(b)
pyramid(c)
exitonclick()
```

Comment: посмотрите мое последнее обновление ответа

Comment: буду ругаться за длинный код! У вас одно и то же повторяется три раза! Если понадобиться что-то изменить (допустим, вы решили добавть еще французский язык. Или фиолетовый цвет), то придется менять в трех местах. Для этого придумали функции. Пишете один раз и применяете в трех местах.

Comment: но у меня же три запроса. Как мне сделать один кусок кода?

Comment: @itped, делаете функцию `get_color` в нее помещаете условия с цветами и в конце вызываете `return`, пример: https://pastebin.com/FSSsJQaE. Учитесь находить повторяющиеся места и оборачивать их в функции

Answer (score 1):

Можно завести словарь в котором разные ключи (слова на разных языках) будут указывать на один цвет, например для цвета `red` будет два ключа: `красный` и `red`. И в функцию  `color` передавать не полученное от пользователя слово, а значение из словаря, соответствующее этому слову (ключу).

```
from turtle import*

a = input("Цвет первой полосы: ")
b = input("Цвет второй полосы: ")
c = input("Цвет третьей полосы: ")

dictionary = {
    'red' : 'red',
    'красный' : 'red',

    'blue' : 'blue',
    'синий' : 'blue',

    'green' : 'green',
    'зелёный' : 'green',
}

def pyramid(c1, c2, c3):
    width(50)

    penup()
    goto(-100, -100)

    color(dictionary[c1])
    pendown()
    forward(200)

    penup()
    goto(60, -50)
    left(180)

    color(dictionary[c2])
    pendown()
    forward(120)

    penup()
    goto(-30, 0)
    left(180)

    color(dictionary[c3])
    pendown()
    forward(60)

pyramid(a, b, c)
exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так

```
color_red=["red","красный"]
input_text = input('Введите ваш текст: ')


if input_text in color_red:
    c = "red"
else:
    print(False)
```

еще можно строкой

```
input_text = input('Введите ваш текст: ')
color_red_1="red красный"

if input_text in color_red_1.split():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

как предложили в комментариях

```
input_text = input('Введите ваш текст: ')

if input_text == 'red' or input_text =='красный':
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

**UPD**
для передачи в функцию

```
input_text = input('Введите ваш текст: ')
input_text1 = input('Введите ваш текст: ')

#создаем словарь всех нужных цветов
colors = {
    'red': 'красный red',
    'green': 'зеленый green',
}

#получаем введенный цвет
def color(input_text):
    for (key, value) in colors.items():
        for a in value.split():
            if a == input_text:
                return key

#передаем его в параметр для использования в дальнейших функциях
color1 = color(input_text)
color2 = color(input_text1)

print(color1,color2)
```

Comment: Ваш код выполняет проверку введенного значения, но ТС хочет унифицировать результат ввода пользователя и дальше с ним работать.

Comment: @mkkik изначально в вопросе было только "Как в python с помощью условного оператора сделать программу, которая понимала бы русский и английский вариант
"

Comment: Значит, ТС плохо сформулировал вопрос, такое бывает.

Comment: @mkkik получается так. исправил под переформулированный вопрос .

Comment: Отличное решение. Взял на заметку

Answer (score -2):

вы реализуете словарь например.

```
colors = {
    'red': 'красный',
    'green': 'зеленый',
    'blue': 'голубой',
    'black': 'черный',
}
```

а дальше, используя ищете среди key

```
color='green'

for (key, value) in colors.items():
    if key == color:print(value)
```

Comment: госпада, кто минусовал. хотябы объясните за что минусы идут.

Comment: я кстати тоже не понял, за что 2 минуса...  судЯ по всему за непоследовательность кода. Но я исправил

Comment: @Интик я хоть и не минусовал, но в этом ответе связь с вопросом на прослеживается. Это ответ на что-то другое.

Comment: ну я для примера дал код) Ну ок, исправил под конкретную задачу.

Comment: Во-первых, зачем перебирать словарь, если хотим получить значение по ключу? Во-вторых, если пользователь ввел цвет на кириллице, ничего не произойдет вообще.